# Java Ant Error : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm a beginner with Ant but I have a problem when I try to use JUnit :

```
<target name="test" depends="compile" description="JUnit Tests">
    <junit printsummary="yes" failureproperty="junit.failure" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="junit.classpath"/>
        <classpath path="${myAntTestBin.dir}"/>
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        <test name="fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

But now, I have these errors :

```
test:
    [junit] Running fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest
    [junit] Testsuite: fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit]
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    [junit]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    [junit]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    [junit]
    [junit] Test fr.isima.myAntTest.ProjectTest FAILED
```

What is the problem ?
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
<test name="${myAntTestBin}/ProjectTest.class"/>
```

It's looking for the name of the class, not the location:

```
<test name="ProjectTest"/>
```

... with a package name qualifying it if appropriate (which you really should have, of course). So for example:

```
<test name="foo.bar.ProjectTest" />
```

And *also*, as JB Nizet mentions, this:

```
<classpath path="${myAntTestBin}"/>
```

should be:

```
<classpath path="${myAntTestBin.dir}"/>
```

to match your declaration:

```
<property name="myAntTestBin.dir" value="../myAntTest/bin/fr/isima/myAntTest"/>
```

EDIT: Now that you've edited the question (completely) it looks like you've got the wrong classpath, and it should actually be:

```
<property name="myAntTestBin.dir" value="../myAntTest/bin"/>
```

The classpath should be the *base* of directory structure containing your classes. This is just like in normal Java when you'd run:

```
java -cp bin foo.bar.Baz
```

if you had a directory structure of `bin/foo/bar` containing `Baz.class`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the classpath with the package name as you said but there are still some errors (I have edited my question).

Comment: @bryan63: You've now made this answer look completely silly as it doesn't reflect your question at all. It would have been better to *add* to your question rather than getting rid of the first version.  However, it looks like your classpath is wrong - will edit the answer to explain.

Comment: Thank you, the class is found, but now the problem is that my tests use classes from a different package : my class test is in : "fr.isima.myAntTest" and the other classes are in : "fr.isima.MyAnt2". It's actually 2 different projects, how to join these packages to do my tests ?

Comment: @bryan63: You need to put all the different directories in your classpath. With all these problems, I wonder whether combining Ant and JUnit is possibly a little advanced for you. If you're fairly new to Java and on your own (rather than in a team where people can help you in a hands-on way) it might be best to start off just running the tests in Eclipse or Netbeans.